# How to understand "UI Thread" coverage from source code in WP

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I wonder whether it is possible to understand which code pieces are executed on UI from source code just depending on static analysis in Windows Phone development.

I try to implement a static analysis finding places in which Dispatcher.(Begin)Invoke is used unnecessarily.

These are the places that UI thread definitely executes:

- event handlers which gets "RoutedEventArgs" as a parameter
- Constructors of UI elements
- the definitions of method calls in above methods (means that transitively looking at call graphs of these event handler methods and UI constructors)

Is there any other place or is there something wrong about above list?

Answer (score 0):

Every method called by using the Dispatcher or the right SynchronizationContext will execute on the UI thread. That makes exhaustive static analysis impossible. For instance, the callback of the WebClient class executes on the UI thread. How are you supposed to predict those corner cases?

A quick tip though, quite useful is you have a method that can be called both from a UI or a non-UI thread. By calling the method `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` (this method isn't shown by the intellisense in Visual Studio, so it's hard to discover), you can know if you need to call the Dispatcher or not:

```
if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    // In the UI thread
    SomeMethod();
}
else
{
    // Not in the UI thread
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(SomeMethod);
}
```

From there, you can write a wrapper:

```
public void CallDispatcherIfNeeded(Action method) // You might want a shorter name
{
    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        // In the UI thread
        method();
    }
    else
    {
        // Not in the UI thread
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(method);
    }
}
```

And then you just have to call it, without worrying whether you're on the UI thread or not:

```
CallDispatcherIfNeeded(SomeMethod);
```

That said, if your code is correctly written, it's quite rare to need this kind of trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at when Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is actually needed, not the other way around.

It is almost never needed, excepted when handing an async completed event which may start out on a background thread, and thus if you want to do something with the UI, you need to marshal it over to the UI thread.

In other words, unless you need to do something with the UI from a background thread, you don't need it.

Greg